# Troubles with using else if function on JavaScript (not showing up on console.log)

Tags: javascript

These are my codes:

```
// Array for game options (*added the array as requested*)            
const picks = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

// Computer's new pick            
const compNewChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
console.log("Computer chose " + picks[compNewChoice]);

// Player's new pick          
const playerNewChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * picks.length);
console.log("Player chose " + picks[playerNewChoice]);

if (compNewChoice === picks[0]) {
    if (playerNewChoice === picks[1]) {
        console.log("Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[1] + " Player Wins!");
    } else if (playerNewChoice === picks[2]) {
        console.log("Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[2] + " Computer Wins!");
    } else {
        console.log(" It's a Draw! Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[0]);
    }          
}
```

But when the script runs the 2 conditions, computer choses picks[0] and player choses picks[2] are met, it only shows
"Computer chose picks[0]"
"Player chose picks[2]"

It doesn't show:
"Computer chose picks[0] and Player chose picks[2] Computer Wins!"

---

I tried splitting up the code:

```
    if (compNewChoice === playerNewChoice) {
        console.log("It's a Draw");    
    }

    if (compNewChoice === picks[0]) {
        if (playerNewChoice === picks[1]) {
            console.log("Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[1] + " Player Wins!");
        } else if (playerNewChoice === picks[2]) {
            console.log("Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[2] + " Computer Wins!");
        }
    }
```

The part where it draws will show up fine, but the ones below will not be correct.

Comment: Need more context around the same. Can u add more code? with dummy data if possible.

Comment: You're using strict equality (`===`). Is it possible that `playerNewChoice` and the elements in the `picks` array are two different types eg a string and a number? But yes, please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were comparing the `index` with the actual `item`. Here is the correct comparison:

```
picks[compNewChoice] === picks[0]
```

It works as you expected.

```js
const picks = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

const compNewChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); 
console.log("Computer chose " + picks[compNewChoice]);

const playerNewChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * picks.length); 
console.log("Player chose " + picks[playerNewChoice]);


if (picks[compNewChoice] === picks[0]) {
    if (picks[playerNewChoice] === picks[1]) {
        console.log("Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[1] + " Player Wins!");
    } else if (picks[playerNewChoice] === picks[2]) {
        console.log("Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[2] + " Computer Wins!");
    } else {
        console.log(" It's a Draw! Computer chose " + picks[0] + " and Player chose " + picks[0]);
    }          
}
```